# Adding large amount of data to web map using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping

I've got problem, I'm creating map based application, and now I have to add to map about 100 000 graphic points, from coordinates.

I was trying in many ways to do it, but always process of adding points takes about 7-10 seconds, or my web browser just hang on.

is it even possible to add this amount of data to map without having problems with performance?

I'm using ArcGIS API for JavaScript with ArcGIS Server 9.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok mates, I found an answer here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/limits_for_graphics.htm

it turns out, that in my case the best option will be displaying data via WMS service as raster.

thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 3):

it is all about browser... and you know that this is the difference between an web application and native application...

when u add more data as 100000 points to map as feature, normally browser hangs up...

**the solution:**

1. Use WMS service or REST service from arcgis server.
2. Check Out cluster strategy for adding logical point
3. BBOX
4. Get points specific zoom range with intersecting with seeing extent...
5. Dont add more points :)

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I'm using right now a REST service, the WMS service was far to slow for this situation. I have to show points in whole region of country, so I can not set dependence between my points and scale, or restrain it with BBOX. Maybe some kind of points generalization? I dont know, cant figure it out somehow