# Render huge amount of points on a map

Tags: web-mapping, open-source-gis, software-recommendations, map-point

I already had a look at [Rendering huge amount of points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44578)

My situation is, I have huge amount of points (about 1 million). I have to display these points on a map. I searched but I found ArcGIS solutions. I want an open source one.

I started of with Leaflet. In Leaflet, we can cluster the points, but I can't do that, because my points represent a trend on surface of the Earth, and cluster loses that information.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an open source solution, try with **[CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/)**. For instance, you can make a **[density grid map](http://developers.cartodb.com/examples/density-grid.html)** or an **[intensity map](http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials/intensity_map.html)** (heatmap). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to do any filtering/querying after rendering these points? If not, you can have a look at [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) and use it for serving your data as raster images via [WMS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms). You can also use a webmap server even for filtering and some SQL-like queries with [WFS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs).

If you want to represent a trend on Earth surface, it might be OK not to display some of the points (at some zoom levels).

Serving this layer via map server seems to be the number one option to me as a milion of points is really a huge number to serve via canvas/svg to Leaflet. You did not mention what format your data is distributed in, but Geoserver should handle (nearly?) any standard geometry format (SHP, KML, JSON).

Comment: i will query by clicking the poits. But I like the idea.

Comment: my data is shp file. bt can I make a transparent wms layer?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [mapsdata](http://www.mapsdata.co.uk/) its a free online application to plot geospatial information on custom maps. Mapsdata provides various interactive visualization options like [Pins](http://www.mapsdata.co.uk/portfolio-items/mapping-crime-in-london/), [heatmap](http://www.mapsdata.co.uk/portfolio-items/mapping-crime-in-london/), [clusters](http://www.mapsdata.co.uk/portfolio-items/mapping-crime-in-london/) and [bubble map](http://www.mapsdata.co.uk/portfolio-items/map-world-millionaires-bilionaires/) to analyse information to make better decisions and information can easily be shared/export as an image or iframe embed code.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create mapbox vector tiles (MBTILES) with protobuff /pbf in tiles table tile_data blob field. Use leaflet, open layers or mapbox gl js . Create them with tippecanoe or mapbox studio classic.or mapbox studio online. You can control at what zoom levels points drop . https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe